# CSS in IE9, some style rules are not applied

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

I'm debugging a style problem in Internet Explorer 9.

It look's like ie9 doesn't apply all style rules defined in my css file. As I look in the network tab of Developer Tools, I see for example the '.mobileMenu' class present. 
But the style is not applied to the element, if I use 'Inspect element', the browser simply doesn't know about any related style rules. A large portion of the css file (but not all of it) is simply ignored by ie9.

It works in Chrome, Firefox and IE 10. There are a couple of CSS validation errors, but none that look really troubling.

My guess, which is a guess, is that perhaps some stylesheet property (CSS3?) is causing ie9 to stop rendering and skip the rest of the file. Is that possible? 
Anyone any experience?

Thanks !

Comment: show us the CSS that `.mobileMenu` has, and maybe we can answer that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end, it had nothing to do with CSS3.

Ie9 did stop rendering, not because of anything in the css file itself, but because the style sheet was to large..

According to Microsoft:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/10164546.aspx

We split the Style Sheet into two seperate files and the problem was resolved.

Comment: That's definitely good to know, well done finding your own answer. You should accept this if this is what solved your problem :)

Comment: I have to wait to tomorrow to mark my answer :). Thanks for your response, it took us some time to figure this one out!

Comment: This was our case, it was driving my crazy all day long. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

Some CSS3 properties are not accepted by IE9. See [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp) for which browsers support which properties.

Comment: I well aware of the fact that some properties are not supported. But I'm wondering what happens when IE9 finds those properties in the style sheet. I always assumed that it would just skip those properties, but it looks like the rendering is just canceled for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

If the CSS3 properties are not support by IE9, you can try using a plugin like:[CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/)